# React Native InAppBrowser error "Cannot read property 'isAvailable' of null"

Tags: react-native, inappbrowser

I'm trying to call the inAppBrowser function after a user is created in the sign up form. For some reason I keep getting the error

```js
Cannot read property 'isAvailable' of null.
```

But if I log InAppBrowser it clearly tells me that it is an object. So whats the deal?

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import AuthContent from "../components/Auth/AuthContent";
import { createUser } from "../util/auth";
import LoadingOverlay from "../components/ui/LoadingOverlay";
import { InAppBrowser } from "react-native-inappbrowser-reborn";

function SignupScreen() {
  const [isAuthenticating, setIsAuthenticating] = useState(false);

  const inAppBrowser = () => {
    console.log(InAppBrowser);
    InAppBrowser.isAvailable()
      .then(() => {
        return InAppBrowser.open("https://www.google.com", {
          // ios Properties
          animated: true,
          modalEnabled: true,
          //Android Properties
          showTitle: true,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  async function signupHandler({ email, password }) {
    setIsAuthenticating(true);
    await createUser(email, password);
    setIsAuthenticating(false);
    inAppBrowser();
  }

  if (isAuthenticating) {
    return <LoadingOverlay message={"Creating user..."} />;
  }

  return <AuthContent onAuthenticate={signupHandler} />;
}

export default SignupScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be going wrong with the installation of the package.

For Android:

Add the following in `android/build.gradle`:

```
    targetSdkVersion = 34
    androidXAnnotation = "1.2.0"
    androidXBrowser = "1.4.0"
```

Make sure that `androidXBrowser` is `1.4.0`.

Add the following in `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
implementation project(':react-native-inappbrowser-reborn')
```

Add the following in `android/settings.gradle`:

```
include ':react-native-inappbrowser-reborn'
project(':react-native-inappbrowser-reborn').projectDir = new 
File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native- 
inappbrowser-reborn/android')
```

Add the following in `MainApplication.java`:

```
import com.proyecto26.inappbrowser.RNInAppBrowserPackage;

@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
...
packages.add(new RNInAppBrowserPackage());
...
}
```

Now do a `cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..` and rebuild the app.

For ios:

1. Do a pod installation.
2. Add the following in the ios/Podfile:

   `pod 'RNInAppBrowser', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-inappbrowser-reborn'`

Now rebuild the app. Close metro and restart.

This solved my issue, hope it works for you.